# Linking SFML audio in linux?

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

What librarys i need to link when i want to use 
i have

```
if(! sb.loadFromFile("Intro.wav")){
    exit(-1);
}
intro.setBuffer(sb);
intro.setLoop(true);
intro.play();
```

I tried with

```
g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-audio  Menu.o
```

but compiler is throwing errors like

```
undefined reference to `sf::SoundBuffer::SoundBuffer()'
undefined reference to `sf::Sound::Sound()'
```

Comment: Order might be significant. Try putting `sfml-system` last. Or `Menu.o` first. Or use `$(pkg-config sfml-all --libs)`

Comment: Can you post the **full** command you are using to compile/link?

Comment: Thanks a lot .
$(pkg-config sfml-all --libs)  works.

Answer (score 1):

The linking order matters.

I tend to follow the "depends-on" rule. If X depends on Y, then X has to come before Y. All the SFML modules depend on the SFML system module, so the system module needs to come last. Additionally your object files depend on SFML, so they need to come before the SFML libs.

```
g++ main.o Menu.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-audio -lsfml-system
```